# SSL unknown protocol error using Twython on Python 2.6

Tags: python, ssl, twython

I'm trying to run Twython behind a proxy. Here are the client_args:

```
client_args = {
'verify': False,
'headers': {
    'User-Agent': 'AgentName'
},
'proxies': {
    'http': 'proxy:port_number',
    'https': 'proxy:port_number'
},
'timeout': 120
}
```

Running anything from the API runs into this error:

```
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Any workaround is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into one of the problems with [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) which is that it cannot handle the CONNECT HTTP command, primarily because [urllib3](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3) doesn't support it.  [This article](http://lukasa.co.uk/2013/07/Python_Requests_And_Proxies/) goes into more detail about the reasons for this and why urllib3 has not been updated to handle this.  The article also includes an **unsafe** (and not recommended) work around you can try:

```
proxies = {'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'}
```

Obviously replace the IP and port with whatever the settings your proxy server has.

You might also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669457/python-httplib-ssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol), which addresses the same error with httplib and some solutions that worked there and might be adaptable.  Maybe.

EDIT: You're missing a comma after the second proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was trying to run SSLv23 which is unsupported under Python 2.7. Switching to SSL3 fixed it.