# Not able to connect to https sites using urllib due to ssl error

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, urllib

```
fh = urllib.urlopen('https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html',proxies=proxies)
```

where proxies is a dictionary as follows:

```
proxies['http'] = "http//user_name:password@ip:port"
proxies['https'] = "https//user_name:password@ip:port"
```

NOte: I have removed colon after http and https above because it is taken as a link and i am not allowed to post more than 2 links.

but i get following error:

```
407      def _real_connect(self, addr, return_errno):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I tried what was given on "[Python httplib SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669457/python-httplib-ssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol)" but that gave me following error:

```
 407     def _real_connect(self, addr, return_errno):
 IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Now it might be because of college proxy but i have supplied it through proxies.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the `:` in the URIs:

```
proxies['http'] = "http://user_name:password@ip:port"
proxies['https'] = "https://user_name:password@ip:port"
```

Comment: Actually i have given colon but put it in a note here because stackexchange was treating it as a url which i didn't want to happen as i can post only 2 link.