# MS WindowsServer 2012: Python request - SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol

Tags: python, windows, github

on MS Windows Server 2012 the Python script is doing https request to open github repository, see full log at

https://github.com/scisoft/autocmake/issues/15#issuecomment-115878039

The problem is (Python 2.7.10) only with Windows Server 2012 connection to https sites of github, which are open for public. On all other Windows computers (including CI service on appveyor.com) this connection works.

Maybe this is issue related to Windows Server 2012. Any help please how to modify this line to make the Python connection working  ?

update.fetch_url('https://github.com/miroi/autocmake/raw/master/update.py',   'update.py')

Comment: The usual causes are http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html. Maybe this is related to python only? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669457/python-httplib-ssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol)